# Empty array in near using geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, geocoder

I'm using [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder).
I want to get near locations but it's returning a empty array.

Got this in database:

```
"id": 5,
"name": "sogra2",
"lat": "-22.833575",
"long": "-43.312882",
```

This is my action using the near coordenates

```
def near
  @near = Test.near([-22.844279, -43.306174], 100, :units => :km)
  render json: @near
end
```

This is my model:

```
class Test < ApplicationRecord
  reverse_geocoded_by :lat, :long
end
```

Posting the Query

```
SELECT tests.*, (111.19492664455873 * ABS(tests.lat - -22.844279) *
0.7071067811865475) + (96.29763124613503 * ABS(tests.long - -43.306174) * 0.7071067811865475) AS distance, CASE WHEN (tests.lat >= -22.844279 AND tests.long >= -43.306174) THEN 45.0 WHEN (tests.lat < -22.844279 AND tests.long >= -43.306174) THEN 135.0 WHEN (tests.lat < -22.844279 AND tests.long < -43.306174) THEN 225.0 WHEN (tests.lat >= -22.844279 AND tests.long < -43.306174) THEN 315.0 END AS bearing FROM "tests" WHERE (tests.lat BETWEEN -23.74360060591873 AND
-21.94495739408127 AND tests.long BETWEEN -44.282039151718706 AND -42.33030884828129) ORDER BY distance ASC
```

It's returning `[]`

Rails 5.1 API mode

Comment: What happens when you run the SQL generated above? (ie not the ruby version, but the in-database version)

Comment: @TarynEast I'm using SQLite...how can I test it?

Comment: Dunno - i use postgres... surely that's something you can google for though :)

Answer (score 0):

do you use rails > 4.1?

> ## [Note on Rails 4.1 and Greater](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#note-on-rails-41-and-greater)
>
> Due to a change in ActiveRecord's count method you will need to use `count(:all)` to explicitly count all columns `("*")` when using a near scope. Using near and calling count with no argument will cause exceptions in many cases.

Comment: Yes. Raios 5.1 API mode